# How to set optional variables in Function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable-definitions

When using `Function`, is it possible to set specific arguments to be optional? For instance, in

```
f = Function[{x, y}, x + y];
```

Can I set `y` to a default value (0, for example) if it is not given?

**Thoughts:** I know I can do

```
f[x_, y_: 0] := x + y
```

So I thought

```
f[x_, y_ : 0] := Function[{x, y}, x + y]
```

would work, but that does not seem to be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The problem with `f[x_, y_ : 0] := Function[{x, y}, x + y]` doesn't really have anything to do with whether `Function` arguments can be optional (and I don't think there is a "natural" way to do that anyway). The problem is that the form of `Function` you're using requires symbols to be provided for the formal arguments. Evaluating `f[a]` will result in `Function[{a, 0}, a + 0]`, which doesn't make sense. And without using optionality, `f[1, 2]` gives `Function[{1, 2}, 1 + 2]`.

Comment: So, is your problem how to define a `Function` expression with `SetDelayed`, or is it truly about how to make `Function` work with optional arguments?

Comment: The question is clear enough. Read again.

Comment: You are nearly there. You only need correct syntax. Try: `f[x_, y_ : 0] := x + y`. Then f[1] results in 1 and f[1,2] results in 3.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, I did try that (see "Thoughts"), but I would like to specifically use `Function`.

Comment: Maybe something like: `f=Function[If[Length[{##}] == 1, #0[##, 0], Function[{x, y}, x + y][##]]]`? I am not sure how you want `f[a,b,c]` to evaluate.

Comment: You may use "Function" but you have to remember that "Function" needs argumnets. Therefore, you would write: "f[x_, y_ : 0] = Function[{x, y}, x + y][x, y]"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, taking your question at face value, you can do the following if you're willing to make the following assumption:

All of the arguments with default values are at the right/tail end of the argument sequence, and specifically, we rely only on argument position, not any sort of "typing".

```
FDefaultValues = {1, 17, 999};

f = Function[, With[{fullArgs = PadRight[{##}, 3, FDefaultValues]}, doStuff[fullArgs]]];
f[33, 44, 55]
(* doStuff[{33, 44, 55}] *)

f[33, 44]
(* doStuff[{33, 44, 999}] *)

f[33]
(* doStuff[{33, 17, 999}] *)

f[]
(* doStuff[{1, 17, 999}] *)
```

You can adjust this if some of the leading arguments are not optional.

#### Update

It realized it would be better to parameterize the function creation with the defaults:

```
g[defaults_List] := 
  Function[, With[{fullArgs = PadRight[{##}, 3, defaults]}, doStuff[fullArgs]]];

g1 = g[{a, b, c}]
(* Function[Null, With[{fullArgs = PadRight[{##1}, 3, {a, b, c}]}, doStuff[fullArgs]]] *)

g1[]
(* doStuff[{a, b, c}] *)

g1[11, 22]
(* doStuff[{11, 22, c}] *)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I will try it later. Thanks!